# Pentaho CDE SQL Query with numerical param

Tags: sql, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I would like to know if it is possible to perform an SQL query and pass it a numerical parameter. Let's suppose that I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(cuatrimestre,' Cuatrimestre') As quarter
,   ROUND(SUM(fact_Ventas.cantidad * precioUnitario),0) as amount
FROM fact_Ventas 
INNER JOIN dim_Tiempos ON 
fact_Ventas.idAnio = dim_Tiempos.idAnio AND 
fact_Ventas.idMes = dim_Tiempos.idMes AND 
fact_Ventas.idDia = dim_Tiempos.idDia
INNER JOIN dim_Clientes ON dim_Clientes.idCliente = fact_Ventas.idCliente
INNER JOIN dim_Productos ON dim_Productos.idProducto = fact_Ventas.idProducto
WHERE 
    CAST(fact_Ventas.idAnio As Char) LIKE ${paramAnio} AND
    CAST(fact_Ventas.idMes As Char) LIKE ${paramMes} AND
    CAST(fact_Ventas.idVendedor As Char) LIKE ${paramVendedores} AND
    CAST(fact_Ventas.origen As Char) LIKE ${paramOrigen} AND
    dim_Productos.marca LIKE ${paramMarca} AND
    dim_Clientes.segmentoCliente LIKE ${paramSegmento} 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I want to divide the column amount, by a numerical value extracted from a simple parameter. I managed to use filters in the where clause, but I can not make a division in a column.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(cuatrimestre,' Cuatrimestre') As cuatrimestre
,   ROUND( (SUM(fact_Ventas.cantidad * precioUnitario)/${paramValue}),0) as Importe
FROM fact_Ventas 
INNER JOIN dim_Tiempos ON 
fact_Ventas.idAnio = dim_Tiempos.idAnio AND 
fact_Ventas.idMes = dim_Tiempos.idMes AND 
fact_Ventas.idDia = dim_Tiempos.idDia
INNER JOIN dim_Clientes ON dim_Clientes.idCliente = fact_Ventas.idCliente
INNER JOIN dim_Productos ON dim_Productos.idProducto = fact_Ventas.idProducto
WHERE 
    CAST(fact_Ventas.idAnio As Char) LIKE ${paramAnio} AND
    CAST(fact_Ventas.idMes As Char) LIKE ${paramMes} AND
    CAST(fact_Ventas.idVendedor As Char) LIKE ${paramVendedores} AND
    CAST(fact_Ventas.origen As Char) LIKE ${paramOrigen} AND
    dim_Productos.marca LIKE ${paramMarca} AND
    dim_Clientes.segmentoCliente LIKE ${paramSegmento} 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

But it gives an error and the data is not loaded. The syntax of the query was tested in the database and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the parameter type to Numeric? It defaults to String which was probably fine for your other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot to assign the parameter to the component, I had associated it with SQL Query but not with the component.